# Retriving a JSON in PHP from AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Its my first time sending JSON to server and I have no idea why my PHP script is not receiving the call.

I think that the problem is in how I am setting the POST variables from the app and I am grabbing the wrong one or not setting `$_POST['search']` as intended.

Could anyone point out how would i get the posted data and also how to set the `$_POST['search']` properly

My `$var` return `0` when I look it from the xcode output.

PHP

```
header('Content-Type: text/json');
$var = (isset($_POST['search']) ? json_decode($_POST['search']) : false);
echo json_encode($var)
```

Objective-C

```
 NSDictionary *myJson=@{@"userID": @"1",
                           @"search":@{@"for":@"routine",
                                       @"page":@"1",
                                       @"orderBy":@"new",
                                       @"type":@"1"}
                           };
   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://192.168.1.64/"];
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
        httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
        NSDictionary *params = myJson;
        NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"http://192.168.1.64/igym/bootstrap.php" parameters:params];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                                                                                NSLog(@"Inside the success block %@",JSON);
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                                                                                                NSLog(@"json text is: %@", JSON);
                                                                                                NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                                                                            }];
        [operation start];
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$_GET`?

Comment: I am supposedly sending it as a POST. The get shows the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are encoding ALL PARAMETERS (including "search") as json:

```
httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
```

So, you can't access it in php using

```
$_POST['search'];
```

the data are not sent via post in this case

You can do two things:

- encode only *the content* of the search dictionary as JSON (and not all parameters)
- access the data through:

:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

$post will contain all your posted data json-encoded like this:

```
{
    search =     {
        for = routine;
        orderBy = new;
        page = 1;
        type = 1;
    };
    userID = 1;
}
```

Comment: I've taken the httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding; and now it works like a charm. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
path:@"http://192.168.1.64/igym/bootstrap.php"
```

You have already specified the client's base URL, so you don't have to put it in the path string. Try to replace this code with the following:

```
path:@"igym/bootstrap.php"
```

Beside this, the other problem is in the way you are posting your params. You should send them like this:

```
NSString *jsonParam = @"{\"userID\": \"1\",
                           \"search\":{\"for\":\"routine\",
                                       \"page\":\"1\",
                                       \"orderBy\":\"new\",
                                       \"type\":\"1\"}
                           }";
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonParam forKey:@"search"];
```

Your param is named "search" in the PHP script and its value is a JSON string.

Please note I'm using backslashes to escape quotes in the NSString.

Comment: Aame result I get 0. Also the example string is wrong... first, you dont need to scape.... just use ' "a": "b" ' ... and second... you are pasing non search parameters(like userID) as search. what you are doing there is the same as what I did....